# Connecting php to postgres

Tags: php, database, postgresql, connection

I have a VM running PostgreSQL (pgAdmin III to be specific) and I am attempting to use red bean to connect to it with no success. It does appear to connect, yet when I send something for the DB to store I get an error... Here is my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
include 'php/third-party/rb.php';
R::setup('pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb',
        '(DBUser)','(MyPassword)');
$book = R::dispense( 'book' );
$book->title = 'Learn to Program';
$book->rating = 10;
$book['price'] = 29.99;
$id = R::store( $book );
?>
```

I don't think it has anything to the code. Here is the error that is getting thrown:

> "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'Could
>   not connect to database (mydb).'..."

Comment: Is your PHP script being run on the same machine as PostgreSQL?

Comment: That `...` is the most important bit. Did you leave that out, or did the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks a bit weird:

```
R::setup('pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb',
    '(DBUser)','(MyPassword)');
```

try removing the parenthesis around `DBUser` and `MyPassword`.

If that still doesn't fix it, your php probably doesn't have php5-pgsql installed.

You can install it with this command (assuming your server is a debian flavour):

```
sudo apt-get install php5-pgsql
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was it! The (DBuser) and (Mypassword) thing where just place holders, probably useless to be concerned I just didn't want to give that info. This worked though! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some points to consider:

1. What do you mean with that "the code appears to connect"? The messages says "Could not connect..." The R::setup and R::dispense calls don't attempt to connect. R::store calls attempts to connect. That's where your error pops up, I would think.
2. As comment from @ChrisForrence asks: are you running the script on the same machine as the db server? If not you have to change 'localhost' in the connect string.
3. Can you connect using the standard postgres cli tool (psql)?
4. Do you have the PDO postgresql drivers installed?
5. Are you running in a SELinux environment and is your script being run by the apache process? If so, does the security context of the apache process allow it to make connections to the postgresql server?

Check these issues.